# I apply a style with javascript, but when I apply a new style (in javascript) the style doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Javascript

```js
const displayScreen = (() =>{
    
    const writesquare = (array) =>{

        let blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
        
        let divCounter = 0;

        blocks.forEach(element => {

            if(array[divCounter] == "x"){
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            }else{
                element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                // console.log(element);
            }

            divCounter++;
        });
    };

    const clearScreen = () => {

        let blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

        blocks.forEach(element => {
            element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        });
    };

    return({writesquare, clearScreen})
})();

const array =  ["x","o","x","o","x","o","x","o","x"];

displayScreen.writesquare(array);
displayScreen.clearScreen();
displayScreen.writesquare(array);
```

```css
#gameBoard {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30px);
}

.block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameBoard">
    <div class="block" id="0"></div>
    <div class="block" id="1"></div>
    <div class="block" id="2"></div>
    <div class="block" id="3"></div>
    <div class="block" id="4"></div>
    <div class="block" id="5"></div>
    <div class="block" id="6"></div>
    <div class="block" id="7"></div>
    <div class="block" id="8"></div>
</div>
```

So its quite simple I have an array of x's and o's and for each x or o a different background color is applied to one of the nine divs. However my displayScreen.writesquare(array) writes these color backgrounds only if displayScreen.clearScreen() hasn't been called, as soon as displayScreen.clearScreen() gets called displayScreen.writesquare(array) refuses to update the background colors. The array is simply ["x","o","x","o","x","o","x","o","x"] and the methods get called in the console in chrome.

Comment: Please present proper [mre]s of issues like this (where's the array here, where do these methods get called?)

Comment: Rather than manipulating inline styles, you should use classes, so that the actual formatting then gets applied via your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a way to change class styles in pure javascript, ie without jquery and such?

Comment: jQuery is written in JavaScript, so yes, of course there is.

Comment: to backup @CBroe comment it would also be easier to apply the class to the parent and use the pseudo-selector `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` to chaneg your background pattern.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className is the old-school way to set an element's classes (but you can only remove one by overwriting the whole string with a new value), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList is the more current way.

Comment: Regardless of class/inline this is working fine for me.

Comment: Yes, can't reproduce the problem either - https://jsfiddle.net/k3wpzrLf/

Comment: @tacoshy :nth-child would surely work here, for alternating squares. But I am guessing the array could also be something like `["x","x","x","o", ...]` at some point in the future.

Comment: No idea what was causing the problem but I switched to just adding and removing predefined classes as suggested by CBroe and works like a charm.